# Recursively read folders and executes command on each of them

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to recurse into folders and then run commands on them, using bash script. Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is unclear.  Do you simply want to use find to execute a command on all the files beneath a given directory?

Comment: the answer is in my down vote then :)

Comment: I just want to rename all the files under a directory

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you want to recurse into directories, executing a command on each file found in those, I would use the `find` command, instead of writing anything using shell-script, I think.

That command can receive lots of parameters, like `type` to filter the types of files returned, or `exec` to execute a command on each result.

For instance, to find directories that are under the one I'm currently in :

```
find . -type d -exec echo "Hello, '{}'" \;
```

Which will get me somehthing like :

```
Hello, '.'
Hello, './.libs'
Hello, './include'
Hello, './autom4te.cache'
Hello, './build'
Hello, './modules'
```

Same to find the files under the current directory :

```
find . -type f -exec echo "Hello, '{}'" \;
```

which will get me something like this :

```
Hello, './config.guess'
Hello, './config.sub'
Hello, './.libs/memcache_session.o'
Hello, './.libs/memcache_standard_hash.o'
Hello, './.libs/memcache_consistent_hash.o'
Hello, './.libs/memcache.so'
Hello, './.libs/memcache.lai'
Hello, './.libs/memcache.o'
Hello, './.libs/memcache_queue.o'
Hello, './install-sh'
Hello, './config.h.in'
Hello, './php_memcache.h'
...
```

Some would say "it's not shell"... But why re-invent the wheel ?

*(And, in a way, it is shell ^^ )*

For more informations, you can take a look at :

- `man find`
- lots of tutorials found with google, like, for instance, [Unix Find Command Tutorial](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/Find/find_mini_tutorial.shtml)

Comment: If you need to rename directories as well as files recursively check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268591/unix-rename-files-directories-to-uppercase

Comment: thanks. how would i adjust this to look just for sub-directories of my current directory, and not look for sub-sub directories

Comment: ah. like this: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec echo "Hello, '{}'" \;`

Comment: How do I make it use a function? I have it defined with `wavogg() { stuff }` and `find` just says `'wavogg': No such file or directory`

Comment: Actually, it also doesn't seem to work with `cd`... `find . -type d -exec cd "'{}'" \;`

Answer (score 22):

Bash 4.0 introduced the globstar option, so a construct like:

```
for f in mydir/**/*
do
  # operations here
done
```

...will act recursively on whatever lands in $f.  Turn this on with "shopt -s globstar", otherwise the ** will be treated as a singular *.

Found this gem today at http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option, after being inspired by the zsh construct (which I have enabled by default).

Answer (score 9):

Some basic shells miss commands like 'find' and some of their commands don't support recursivity.
In that case you can use this script to run the desired command in all subdirs in the tree:

```
CDIR=$(pwd)
for i in $(ls -R | grep :); do
    DIR=${i%:}                    # Strip ':'
    cd $DIR
    $1                            # Your command
    cd $CDIR
done
```

If you name the above "recurse.sh" then use:

```
./recurse.sh <command>
```

Example (change the owner/group to 'root' of all files in the tree):

```
./recurse.sh "chown 0:0 *"
```

Comment: awesome, this works perfectlly

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should achieve your goal:

```
function RecurseDirs
{
    oldIFS=$IFS
    IFS=$'\n'
    for f in "$@"
    do
    -----your activity here-----
        if [[ -d "${f}" ]]; then
            cd "${f}"
            RecurseDirs $(ls -1 ".")
            cd ..
        fi
    done
    IFS=$oldIFS
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `find` command and check the switches `-type` (use d to specify directory) and `-exec` (to specify a command to execute).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't understand what you are asking.  The best I can guess with your question is

```
find -type d -exec scriptname.sh \{\} \;
```

Comment: In this case, the script will be executed inside each dir?

Comment: Nope, the script is executed in the location of `find`.

Answer (score 0):

For most recursive file operations, you want to use `find`, as the other answers explain.

There is an example of a recursive bash script included in the [bash-doc](http://packages.debian.org/etch/all/bash-doc/filelist) package. If you've got those examples installed, it will be at `/usr/share/doc/bash/examples/functions/recurse` (on Debian).